# Samba share fails to show soft links

Tags: windows, ubuntu, samba

I have samba share on ubuntu 22.04:

```
[tork]
   path = /
   user = root
   read only = no

   # tried :
   wide links = yes
   force user = root
   allow insecure wide links = yes
```

None of these can be seen from Windows 11:

```
 13 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root          7 Aug  9 11:53 lib -> usr/lib
 14 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root          9 Aug  9 11:53 lib32 -> usr/lib32
 15 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root          9 Aug  9 11:53 lib64 -> usr/lib64
 16 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         10 Aug  9 11:53 libx32 -> usr/libx32
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: "Fails to show" is vague. What does it show instead ?

Comment: @drookie shown are files and folders that are not symbolic links.